# How can I make a particle remove an object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game a player plants a bomb, the bomb explodes creating a fire effect, I would like my fire to be able to kill the player(blue cylinder) and any boxes it collides with. My box and player have colliders. My fire effect is instantiated when the bomb explodes.

How can I make my fire effect destroy my player and box objects?

Can I say something like *`if fire collider hits player collider, destroy player?`*

My code for the bomb is as follows

```
Instantiate(Firebolt, bomb.gameObject.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
```

**Game Layout**

[image: Game Setup]

Answer (score 1):

You can add a collider to Firebolt as well and use OnCollisionEnter on it, checking if the object you hit is a player or a box.

This is a simple example that destroys any player or box it collides with:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
    GameObject other = collision.gameObject;

    // Here I'm using tag to detect if the hit object is a player or a box
    // but you can use name or other methods
    if (other.tag == 'Player' || other.tag == 'Box') {
        Destroy(other);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check out https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnParticleCollision.html

you can apply it to the ParticleSystem or to the target GOs that should react to it.

(u also need to activate collision detection on Particle System AND set it to world.